# FB Send function

Tags: html, facebook-like

not sure if I am being truely stupid, but, I am trying to set up the SEND button on a website and i get an error:

**We encountered the following error when sending your message: Requires
a public email address: To send to an email address, first set up your own
 facebook.com email address**

Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked out this Facebook defect. Five people can reproduce the defect.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302953569717849/?browse=search_4ef37c4b0be953234456497

It's a known bug with their plugin currently for some users (specifically a user that does not have a public facebook.com email address).

So either specify a public email address to get around the bug, or wait for it to get fixed by Facebook.